# Decipher date serial number in Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help deciphering the date number at the end of this url: view-source:http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=XOM&date=1434672000 -- it doesn't look like a proleptic Gregorian serial number, but in Yahoo it designates June 19, 2015. My goal is to write a Python code segment that will create a valid Yahoo date number from my input of yyyymmdd, so that I can generate a valid url for any stock ticker symbol (not just XOM) and option expiration date expressed as yyyymmdd. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a UNIX timestamp -- the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

```
>>> time.gmtime(1434672000)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=170, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: Unix; thanks, I'll look it up. I'm a Python newbie, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) to convert the timestamp into a datetime object:

```
from datetime import  datetime

url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=XOM&date=1434672000"

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(url.rsplit("=",1)[1])))
2015-06-19 01:00:00

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(url.rsplit("=",1)[1])).date())
2015-06-19
```

To create a timestamp using a date string use strptime to create a datetime object and then call [.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
dte = "2015-06-19"
print(datetime.strptime(dte,"%Y-%m-%d").timestamp())
```

Using `urllib.parse` is probably a nicer way to extract the date:

```
from datetime import  datetime

url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=XOM&date=1434672000"

from urllib.parse import parse_qs

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(parse_qs(url)["date"][0])))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was fast. Mind posting an example of how to generate the correct timestamp, given yyyymmdd? Thanks.

Comment: @steve123,  added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you; now I know how to go both ways with the timestamp (deciphering it, and creating it). Regarding creating it, I found out about the calendar module when I discovered the following code for creating a timestamp from a ddmmmyyyy string (I tested this code in the shell):

```
#----------------- Create time stamp
import time
import datetime
import calendar

# oxdt stands for 'option expiration date'
oxdt_txt = '15may2015'
oxdt = datetime.datetime.strptime(oxdt_txt, '%d%b%Y')
print(oxdt_txt)
print(oxdt)
print(calendar.timegm(oxdt.utctimetuple()))
print()

oxdt_txt = '19jun2015'
oxdt = datetime.datetime.strptime(oxdt_txt, '%d%b%Y')
print(oxdt_txt)
print(oxdt)
print(calendar.timegm(oxdt.utctimetuple()))
#----------------- done
```